# Build Tesseract with NDK not working with Cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

i am following [this](http://kurup87.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html) tutorial to get tesseract running on my android project. In step 6.e in the tutorial, it says to ndk-build in Cygwin like this `ndk-build(for windows user, /cygdrive/<ndk-directory>/ndk-build)`. My ndk directory is `C:\Program Files\android-ndk-r8`. but when i try this: `/cygdrive/C:/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build` it, it gives me `No such file or directory error`. The file does exist in the directory mentioned. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: That tutorial is out of date. There's [a better tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build`

There is `ls` command to see what is the contents of folder. So try executing these commands to better understand folder hierarchy:

```
ls /cygdrive
ls /cygdrive/c
ls /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files
...
```